# Convert list[value] to map[value,int countOccurences]

Tags: rascal

Is there an elegant way to count duplicates and write the result to a map.

I know how to do this with traditional loops etc, but I am simply very curious: is there a nice way (eg oneliner) to do this using e.g. comprehensions, reducers or a more traditional Rascal API.

So e.g. convert:

```
list[loc]
```

To

```
map[loc location,int nrOfOccurrencesInListOfThisLocationKey]
```

Tx,

Jos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `distribution` function

```
map[&T element, int occurs] distribution(list[&T] lst)
```

in the `List` library

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Libraries/Prelude/List/List.html#/Rascal/Libraries/Prelude/List/toMap/toMap.html) explains it all. I guess, just put instead of the integers in the first place of the tuple in the example your value and in the second place your number of occurence? Hope it works.